# Why can't I access to assets folder from a simple java class?

Tags: java, android, android-assets

I have an Activity class with the name of FirstClass, and a simple Java class with the name of SecondClass.

Inside of FirstActivity I want to create a new object of SecondClass like this:

```
SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();
```

Inside of the SecondClass, I intend to access the `Assets` folder and process a JSON file and then return the result by a method.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream stream = assetManager.open("myJson.json");
```

But I got an error, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Compiler doesn't know what resources you are trying to get in simple java class. You need a `context` from `Activity` of project from which you want resources. That's why in activity, you didn't get the error and also when you pass the object of resources from Activity, you again didn't get error, because compiler knew about the context and fetched the resources.

Comment: his question is normally, I do not know why some people downvote him. Is it the stigma with old people to newbie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because`getResources()` is the method of Context which is the parent class of the Activity. So, whenever you're trying to calling the following code in the activity:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
```

it's the same as:

```
AssetManager assetManager = YourActivity.this.getResources().getAssets();
```

`YourActivity.this` is the context.

But when you're trying to call it from a class which is not a child of Context, it will gives you an error for `method not found`. You need to either **derive your class from Context** or **pass a context to your class**.

Something like this:

```
public class SecondClass {

  private Context mContext;

  public SecondClass(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
  }

  // then use it on your method
  public void doSomethingWithAsset() {
    AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream stream = assetManager.open("myJson.json");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For accessing resources in your SecondClass, you need an instance of `Context`.

First of all, pass an instance of `Context` to SecondClass:

```
private Context context;

public SecondClass(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    // the rest of your codes ...
}
```

Then use the following code to access the `assets`:

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.context.getAssets(); 
InputStream stream = assetManager.open("myJson.json");
```